# Единицы измерения в Unity

Tags: unity3d

В каких единицах все измеряется в движке Unity?

Хочу сделать карту 255 метров на 255 метров... Я вбиваю в `Terrain` эти размеры и не понимаю - как работать с ландшафтом? Потому что все кажется микроскопическим. И не приблизиться и размер игрока не подогнать под такой мир...

Большие проблемы с масштабированием в общем, как сделать такую карту и за что считать 1 Unit?

Comment: 1 unit = 1 метр, а что значит не приблизиться? колесико+ W клавиша не?

Comment: @Xumera_hZ все обьекты пропадают при приближении, получается что при приближении взгляд камеры просто сквозь обьекты проходит

Comment: выдели объект и нажми F, потом приближай